# Rails test for auto-generating password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, password-encryption

My app allows teachers to start accounts for their students. To avoid the burden of asking teachers to think of passwords for their students, I've written a method to automatically generate passwords. The feature is working correctly in development and production. I' trying to write a test to ensure that this feature continues to work, but the results are not what I expect.

My hunch is that my mistake is in the test:

students_controller_test.rb

```
test "Auto Password" do
    post students_path, params: { student: { first_name:  "Ren",
                                         last_name: "Stimpy",
                                        studentNum: 13},
                                 aula: { seminar_id: @seminar.id } }
    student = assigns(:student)
    assert_equal "rs13", student.username
    assert_equal Student.digest('rs13'), student.password_digest
end
```

And the results:

```
 FAIL["test_Auto_Password", StudentsControllerTest, 2.0619301088154316]
 test_Auto_Password#StudentsControllerTest (2.06s)
        --- expected
        +++ actual
        @@ -1,2 +1 @@
        -# encoding: ASCII-8BIT
        -"$2a$04$1FfqltU9B7yawIs7Z4GWLe9eaaVhFxdPvF9Vg2UWUbYxwqQ5j/9Dm"
        +"$2a$04$CuN1BLKhI/Fx9ueB4QAskOl9Ik.og26TJeeDDF5tdur1erILzjj7W"
        test/controllers/students_controller_test.rb:91:in `block in <class:StudentsControllerTest>'
```

I'm probably misunderstanding something about the way password digestion works. The student's password should be "rs13". So I expected that Student.digest('rs13') should be equal to student.password_digest. Apparently, they're not.

By the way, the password "rs13" comes from a method in my students_controller that automatically creates a username by concatenating the student's initials and student number. The password is also equal to this.

Thank you in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized later that the "authenticate" method is the best way to achieve what I was trying. Simply replace the last line of the test with:

```
assert student.authenticate("rs13")
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `BCrypt::Password will generate the digest with different salt`, so the salt for creating password & checking is different, that is why your test was failed.

Check [this](http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/BCrypt/Password.html#M000009) out, then you can use operator `==` to check the potential credential is correct or not:

```
assert_equal 'rs13', student.password_digest
```

`assert_equal` actually use operator `==` to [compare](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#available-assertions)

Comment: Thank you for the source. Definitely what I was looking for, but I couldn't figure out the exact syntax. "Assert 'rs13' == student.password_dig‌​est" returns false. "Assert_equal 'rs13' == student.password_dig‌​est" gives an error. "Assert 'rs13' == student.password" does work, but since it's testing password instead of password_digest, I was worried that it wasn't a surefire test. I realized I could test what I was after by using student.authenticate‌​. This probably wouldn't have occurred to me without thinking about your response, though. So thanks! – Jeff Zivkovic